# Deserializing multiple keys into single value with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "account_id": 4294967295,
    "player_slot": 0,
    "hero_id": 93,
    "item_0": 170,
    "item_1": 160,
    "item_2": 81,
    "item_3": 208,
    "item_4": 63,
    "item_5": 0,
    "kills": 17,
    "deaths": 6,
    "assists": 8,
    "leaver_status": 0,
    "gold": 2978,
    "last_hits": 80,
    "denies": 0,
    "gold_per_min": 434,
    "xp_per_min": 630,
    "gold_spent": 19090,
    "hero_damage": 16232,
    "tower_damage": 229,
    "hero_healing": 522,
    "level": 25,
    "ability_upgrades": [ <snip> ]
}
```

That I would like to serialize to my model that looks like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MatchDetailPlayerConverter))]
public class MatchDetailPlayer
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public PlayerSlot PlayerSlot { get; set; }
    public Hero Hero { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public int Kills { get; set; }
    public int Deaths { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public LeaverStatus LeaverStatus { get; set; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }
    public int LastHits { get; set; }
    public int Denies { get; set; }
    public int GoldPerMin { get; set; }
    public int XpPerMin { get; set; }
    public int GoldSpent { get; set; }
    public int HeroDamage { get; set; }
    public int TowerDamage { get; set; }
    public int HeroHealing { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public List<AbilityUpgrade> AbilityUpgrades { get; set; }
    public List<AdditionalUnit> AdditionalUnits { get; set; }
}
```

In the JSON there are 6 properties named `item_x` that are ids of items. I would like to deserialize these 6 key/values to one `List<Item>`. My item class is an enum that has the item ids as values.

I have written a custom JsonConverter which can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/0i1cSpcg). My problem is that the converter keeps hitting a stack overflow when `jo.ToObject<MatchDetailPlayer>()` in the `ReadJson()` method of the converter.

What would be causing this infinite loop? Is there a better way to deserialize many key/values to a list of single object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take a look at the implementation of the JsonExtensionData Attribute in your class to modify the deserialization manually
You can find a sample here:
[Json Serialization Attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)